# Plotting data by a matched third string/factor in R

Tags: r, plot, dataframe

I have a data frame in R consisting of LOS, AGE and multiple broader conditions

```
LOS    AGE     broader.condition
  1     75                Spinal
  2     68               Urology
  1     88              Thoracic
  8     76                Spinal
  5     70               Billary
 ...   ...                   ...
```

I'd like to plot AGE vs LOS for each of the broader conditions, that is AGE vs LOS with a matched third column condition in r. This would either be specified by the name (i.e to look specifically at a certain broader condition if required) or automated to run through the entire dataset and plot for each of the broader conditions automatically

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Reproducible similar dataset below

`data <- structure(list(LOS = c(1, 2, 1, 8, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1), ADMISSION_AGE_YEARS = c(75, 
68, 88, 76, 70, 28, 47, 57, 74, 68, 51, 67), broader.condition = structure(c(47L, 
56L, 51L, 47L, 51L, 6L, 3L, 11L, 51L, 3L, 11L, 6L), .Label = c("Acute Liver Failure", 
"Aortic Disease", "Arthritis and Lim Deformity/Fractures", "Asphyxiation", 
"Billary", "Bowel Infection/Perforation/Infarction", "Breast Cancer", 
"Cancer (Unoperated)", "Cardiac Arrest", "Cardiac Arythmia", 
"Cerebral Aneurysm (Non-Ruptured)", "Cerebral Infarction", "Cerebral Oedema", 
"Chronic Liver Disease", "COPD/Asthma/Respiratory Failure", "Drug Overdose and Poisoning", 
"Ear/Nose/Throat", "Electrolyte", "Encephalitis", "Endocrine", 
"Epilepsy", "Gastroectomy", "Gynaecological Cancer/Surgery", 
"Heart Failure", "Hydrocephalus", "Hyperventilation Syndromes", 
"Infection incl. unspecified", "Influenza", "Interstitial Pulmonary Disease", 
"Large Bowel Cancer", "Max Fax Surgeries", "Meningitis", "Myocardial Infarction", 
"Neuro-Surgical Cancer", "Obesity", "Other Inter-Cerebral Haemmorhage", 
"Pancreatitis", "Perforation of Oesophagus", "Peripheral Vascular Disease (Inlc. Ischaemia and Infarction", 
"Pleural Effusion", "Pneumonia", "Psychiatric", "Pulmonary/Veno-Thrombo Embollism", 
"Skin Inflammation/Infection", "Skull and Facial Fractures", 
"Spinal Chord Weakness", "Spinal Surgery/Fractures", "Spinal Trauma", 
"Sub-Arachnoid Haemmorhage", "Systemic Weakness", "Thoracic/Abdominal Aortic Aneurysm (Non-Ruptured)", 
"Thoracic/Abdominal Aortic Aneurysm (Ruptured incl. injury)", 
"Trauma to Intra-Abdominal Organs/Vessels", "Trauma to Thoracic Cage", 
"Traumatic Inter-Cerebral Haemmorhage/Contusions/Oedema", "Urology/Renal Surgery"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("LOS", "ADMISSION_AGE_YEARS", 
"broader.condition"), row.names = c(4L, 5L, 14L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 31L, 33L, 38L, 39L, 40L), class = "data.frame")`

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think using `filter` from the `dplyr` package is a good bet.

Determine unique values for third column:

```
levs <- unique(data$broader.condition)
```

Filter data for a particular condition and plot:

```
  require(dplyr)
  fdata <- filter(data, broader.condition == levs[1])
  plot(fdata$LOS, fdata$ADMISSION_AGE_YEARS, 
       pch=19, xlab= 'LOS', ylab= 'AGE', main= paste0(levs[1]))
```

Or run through a loop to plot all conditions in separate plots:

```
for (i in 1:length(levs))
{
  temp <- filter(data, broader.condition == levs[i])
  plot(temp$LOS, temp$ADMISSION_AGE_YEARS, 
       pch=19, xlab= 'LOS', ylab= 'AGE', main= paste0(levs[i]))
}
```

Alternatively you could easily use `ggplot2` to plot all conditions on the same plot with different colors.

Comment: Filtering by specific condition may be required, so this is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To start with, would this be similar to what you are after for the more generic option?
Using library(ggplot2)

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = ADMISSION_AGE_YEARS, y = LOS)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(. ~ broader.condition) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

or

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = ADMISSION_AGE_YEARS, y = LOS, colour = broader.condition)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Both of these are very useful, especially the second method for isolating those cases with very long length of stays. Thankyou for this.